# foreach in foreach error build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I need to do a loop in another loop and I get a strange error as if it lacked a closing } and I get a compile error on the page. As against the project compiles . the error message is

> CS1513 : } expected.

The source indicates the line of code in 1238 while I was not more than 150 lines of code in the page, really strange . help please

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("VCreateCommande", "CCommande", new { id = "formretouche" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Support papier</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tretouche.Supportpapier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tretouche.Supportpapier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        var i = 1;
        foreach (var item in Model.Tformats)
        {
            var idformat = "idformat" + i;
            var idquantite = "qteformat" + i;
            var idtxt="qte" + @item.Idformat;
            int qteretoucheformat=0;
            foreach (var itemretoucheformat in Model.Tretouchesformats)
            {
                if(itemretoucheformat.IdFormat ==item.Idformat)
                {
                    qteretoucheformat = itemretoucheformat.Quantité;
                }
            }
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-label col-md-2 fltleft">Quantité @item.Format</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 fltleft">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tretoucheformat.Quantité, new { id = idtxt, Name=idtxt })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tretoucheformat.Quantité, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            i = i + 1;
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">Photo...</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tretouche.fichierphoto, new { type = "file" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <input id="idtyperetouche" name="idtyperetouche" type="text" value="@idtyperetouche" class="hdn" />
        <input name="idcommande" type="text" value="@idtyperetouche" class="hdn" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Papier</th>
            <th>Quantite</th>
            <th>Type de retouche</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Tretouches)
        {
            var prix = 0;
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("Papier", item.Supportpapier)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantite)
                </td>
                @foreach (var typeretouche in Model.Ttyperetouches)
                {
                    if (item.Idtyperetouche == typeretouche.Idtyperetouche)
                    {
                        <td>@typeretouche.Libelle</td>
                        prix = (typeretouche.Prix * item.Quantite);
                    }
                }
                <td>
                    <img src="@item.SRCphoto" class="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    @prix   €
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", "TRetouches", new { id = item.Idretouche }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Supprimer", "Delete", "TRetouches", new { id = item.Idretouche }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: I'm ignorant of ASP.NET MVC.  Does it really let you embed HTML in C# without any sort of delimiter to signal the breaks between C# and HTML?

Comment: @paqogomez: It's perfectly legal to have an empty `foreach` body. Not sure why you'd want to, but it'll compile just fine.

Comment: @adv12: The Razor view engine will recognize when you've shifted from C# context to HTML context. There are some exceptions to that but there are ways to get around it when they happen.

Answer (score 4):

For Razor views (at least MVC 4 and earlier), unlike for a .cs file, the { needs to be on its own line

```
foreach (var itemretoucheformat in Model.Tretouchesformats)
{

}
```

Henk's comment suggests this may have been improved in MVC 5.

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least not in the current version.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I'm working with MVC 4, where it is certainly a problem.  Perhaps it was improved in MVC 5.

Comment: I tried to put everything on the same line but it's KO `foreach (var itemretoucheformat in Model.Tretouchesformats){if(itemretoucheformat.IdFormat ==item.Idformat){qteretoucheformat = itemretoucheformat.Quantité;}}`

Comment: hi and tks for help, I have put the complet code. I note that in `@foreach ( var item in Model.Tretouches ){`  , Item is highlighted in red with the following error "A local variable named item can not be Declared in this scope Because It Would give a different Meaning to ' item', which is already used in a Parent or current scope to denote something else . The project compiles but I always get the same error on the page , line 1238 while I have 150. tks for help please

Comment: That means you already have something else called item, though I don't see where from the posted code.  Change that variable name to something else.